# Compare two lists for Max value within a parameter using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Field objects, with a parameter of (string)Name and (int)Size.

I also have a list of File objects, each containing a list of Field objects, in which some of them may appear in the overarching Field objects.

I need to go through all the Field objects, and find the max value of all possible File-Field objects.

I could do this with nesting 3? for loops, but I wanted to see if this is possible in linq.

```
List<fieldobject> mainfields;
List<fileobject> files;
```

within the fileobject class:

```
List<fieldobject> fields;
```

Basic concept in for loops would be:

```
foreach (fieldobject field in mainfields)
    foreach (fileobject file in files)
        foreach (fieldobject fileField in file.fields)
            if (field.name == fileField.name)
                field.size = math.max(field.size,fileField.size);
```

I can replace that if and assignment with a linq, but I was hoping to get rid of most/all of the for loops. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code does not compile (second foreach makes no sense), please provide a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: where is files coming from in the second loop? Should it be `field.files`?

Comment: The main class has:
    list<fieldobject> mainfields
    list<fileobject> files

the fileobject class has:
    list<fieldobject>

I have to loop through all files that are attached to the main object, and compare their fields to the fields directly attached to the main object. the code may be missing some {} but should work as shown

Comment: Please show the definition of `fieldobject` and `fileobject`. And to make sure, you want the max value of `fieldobject.size` among ALL items in all lists?

Comment: @Sach Yes. My mainfields.size needs to be set to the max size from within all fields within the list of files. The match trigger is .name

Comment: `mainfields` is a list. So do you want to set the `Size` of ALL items in the list to the max of that of your file list?

Comment: @Sach mainfields is the overall collective of all possible fields contained within all files, as well as potentially more.

i need to find the max size between mainfields.size, as well as all possible files.fields.size, where the .name property is identical.

Comment: I'm sorry your problem statement is confusing. Please rewrite your question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly `file.fields` is an internal list of fileobject inside fileobject object so you need to use the `SelectMany` extension method:

```
foreach (fileobject field in mainfields)
{
    field.size = files.SelectMany(x => x.fields)
   .Where(y => y.name == field.name).Select(m => m.size).Max();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew this was possible, but I don't have the wheres and selects and select manys down yet. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like;

```
foreach (fieldobject field in mainfields)
{
    int maxFileSize = files.Where(f => f.name == field.name)
                           .Select(f => f.size)
                           .Max();
    if (field.size < maxFileSize)
    {
         field.size = maxFileSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any comparing of .name from mainFields and files.fields